# how to integrate java webservices to salesforce in eclipse

Tags: integration, java

I Want to write java program to fetch records from sql&update it to salesforce(integration) can any one give some idea

Comment: Idea about what ? What have you already researched, we need some specific questions if you want specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably be looking at either the SOAP or the REST api's.

SOAP API

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/

REST API

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/

A good getting starting point for java development can be found here

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Java

Comment: How we can integrate Java and Salesforce using Apache Oltu ? Any guidance on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436388/spring-mvc-apache-oltu-and-salesforce-integration-examples ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to update data in salesforce from outside slesforce, So you have to integrate your java app  to salesforce.you have several options for integrating your app to salesforce.
1.RESTful APIs, such as the Force.com REST API, Bulk API, and Streaming API.
2.Web Services Connector (WSC).